# How to remove the animation when pressing the back button in a navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I guess I'm looking for the method to override so I can set the "animated" parameter to "NO". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code:

```
[myNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]
```

This should help you.

Comment: Where would be the best place to make this call? Thanks Kai. :)

Comment: I don't work with storyboards or IB and so all the pushing and popping programatically...

Answer (score 0):

@GlorytheWz: You can make use of the popViewController code in the back or dismiss or done button which u use to navigate back to the parent view.

```
[myNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]
```

Comment: I'm linking up my views in the Storyboard via "push" and "custom" segues and don't see dedicated back buttons. It's probably something really simple that I'm missing...